# How to store changes in state using contenteditable element?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, contenteditable

How to store changes in state using contenteditable element?

This code store it nicely, but the cursor changes to the beginning of the element.

Do I have to code the cursor position or is there an easy solution?

And no I wont use a form element.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const About = () => {
    const [text, setText] = useState('Hallo');

    return (
        <div className="about">
            <h2>About</h2>
            <div className="title column m-0"
                contentEditable={true}
                suppressContentEditableWarning={true}
                onInput={(e) => { setText(e.target.innerHTML) }}
                onBlur={(e) => { setText(e.target.innerHTML) }}
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: text }}
            ></div>
        </div >
    )
}

export default About;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to store changes and not to have a *controlled* component you can use `onInput` prop. It will store the changed text into your state.

```
 <div
    contentEditable={true}
    suppressContentEditableWarning={true}
    onInput={e => setText(e.currentTarget.textContent)}
 ></div>
```

P.S: The reason that cursor loses focus is that when you `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, you basically are re-mounting every data that you have in your `div` including the cursor position. That's one of the reasons which makes setting HTML in this way, not recommended.

Comment: But what i I have a default value in my state from the beginning?

Comment: @AlexanderJuhl For having a default value you can set what you want inside your `div` like: `<div .... > Default Value </div>`.